# Elasticsearch cannot start

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem to starting the elasticsearch.

ES status as below
[image]

Log as below
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to have two different versions of Elasticsearch 7.17.3 and 7.17.6 on your classpath. You probably need to remove the older one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have two different versions of Elasticsearch 7.17.3 and 7.17.6 on your classpath. You probably need to remove the older one